# Assigning a color to children of an object

Tags: unity-game-engine, colors, children, renderer

I'm trying to assign a bunch of children of an object a random color, however it seems to only assign the *first* child a color, the following children are ignored, it's weird though because through debugging, I can see that is in fact working as intended.

Here's the code:

```
private Color col;
private Component[] children;

void SetClientColor()
{
    children = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();

    col = new Color(Random.Range(0.1f, 1.0f), Random.Range(0.1f, 1.0f), Random.Range(0.1f, 1.0f));
    if (GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>() != null)
    {
        foreach (Renderer child in children)
        {
            Debug.Log("assigning color to " + child);
            GetComponentInChildren<Renderer>().material.color = col;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what happens in game:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: what happens if on the line you assign the color you use `child.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = col;`?

Comment: That worked! You're amazing :) thanks heaps! How can I vote to increase your repuation, I'm new to all this.

Comment: No problem! :) (for future reference, it usually helps if you tag the software you're using, e.g. Unity) As to voting, there should be a small up triangle next to the comment. Thanks!

Comment: There doesn't seem to be one.. could you just copy and paste your answer into the answer comment field? Pretty sure I can upvote you there! Cheers, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: It appears when you mouse over the comment on the left side. It's ok. That really was meant to be a comment answer so no formal answer acceptance needed!

Comment: Literally nothing coming up, sorry man. Thanks again for the help :)